# Display/Hide part of a list

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, list, repeater

I have an (unordered)list (generated by a repeater) of items. However, I'd like to show the first three items, and have the rest hidden by the `main content` div. When a button is pressed, I would like the list's div to expand, pushing the `main content` div down and showing the rest of the list. I was thinking of using slideDown(), but that closes the entire div ( and I would like to show the first 3 items of the list). What would be the best way to achieve an effect like this? Is there a plugin that can easily show X items of a list and the display the rest upon request?

Thanks

edit: Adding current code:

```
   <div id="name_links">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptName" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <ul class="ul_links">
        <li>

        <a id="aName"  runat="server" href=<%# Eval("Name")%> >
    <%# Eval("Name")%> 
      </a>

        </li>
        </ul>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>

<div id="main_content" >
...
</div>
```

I've tried to add this JQuery, but it doesn't seem to pick up any of the links:

```
    $("ul.ul_links").each(function() {
        $(this).children("li:gt(3)").hide();

        alert("Testing"); //This never gets called. 
    });
```

Comment: are you doing `$("ul.ul_links").each(....);` inside `$(document).ready(...)`?

Comment: Hi. Yes, it's inside `$(document).ready(...)`. There are other codes there that do get executed fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You item template looks wrong

It should be

```
 <div id="name_links">
     <ul class="ul_links">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptName" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <li>

    <a id="aName"  runat="server" href=<%# Eval("Name")%> ><%# Eval("Name")%> 
  </a>

    </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then jquery will be able to show and hide as desired.

The other way you were creating sets of ul -> li tags .

Comment: I tried moving the `<ul>` tags outside, but it didn't work. The CSS also broke for all the items except the first one. Unless, my CSS is wrong (because I've been using my original method)?

Comment: Ah that was it. I edited my CSS and the styling is now fine as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with jQuery, but it would help to see example of your markup.

Here's a [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/show-top-items-li-s-of-ul-s) showing how you could do it with ul/li tags. You should be able to adapt it to your own markup without too much trouble.

Typically you hide item 4 and out with:

```
$('div:gt(2)').hide(); //index starts at 0
```

You have to modify the jquery selector to fit your markup and you could put it in a `$(document).ready()` block in order to hide the items on page load.